# How to use * keyword in asp.net core services.AddCors

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cors

I want to set `all localhost port` can allow `CORS` and then i tried to use `*` keyword to do it , like below code :

```
readonly string MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //..
    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
            builder =>
            { 
                builder.WithOrigins($"http://localhost:*");
            }
        );
    });
    //..
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    //..
    app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);
    //..
}
```

but it not work :
[image]

csproj :

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Dapper" Version="2.0.35" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SqlClient" Version="4.8.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: did you remember to call `IApplicationBuilder.UseCors()?`

Comment: @Paul Keister yes ![image](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/12729184/87493386-46d91700-c67f-11ea-8a55-b28a20741836.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to set all localhost port can allow CORS

To achieve above requirement, you can try:

```
services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
        builder =>
        {
            builder.SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => new Uri(origin).Host == "localhost");
        }
    );
});
```